# Lucene frontend / GUI

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am using hibernate-core and hibernate-search. Like I can take a look to the persisted entities with hibernate-core using some database-frontend, I need a frontend for hibernate-search/lucene to take a look at the lucene index.

I tried the latest luke, but it is alpha and does not work correctly for me.

Solr seems to have some web-frontends. But it is an alternative to hibernate-search, and it is hard to integrate with, if I understand everything I read correctly.

My wish is to see, what terms are indexed for specific entites (and its relations).

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: Try [Dmitry Kan's mavenised version of Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases).  It is up to date with the latest version of lucene (4.9).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Hibernate Search Eclipse plugin:

- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hibernate-search-plugin

[image]

[image]

Introduced first on [the Hibernate Search blog](http://in.relation.to/2016/01/22/EclipseToolsForHibernateSearch/).